# Running UFT test through Amazon Web Services instance of UFT

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, automation, scheduled-tasks, hp-uft

Due to the budget that we currently have and only needing to run UFT for maybe an hour a day, we are trying to integrate an Amazon Web Services instance of UFT since they charge by the hour.

My question is this:
We are trying to run our test at 9am every day, we already have a vba script that opens the correct test and runs it successfully through a windows scheduled task, is this possible if we are using an AWS instance of UFT? I have never used AWS so I am not aware of any restrictions or complications that might arise.

I guess what I am looking for is how would we go about logging in to AWS, make sure that the UFT instance is being used, and run a test all without having to touch anything

Answer (score 2):

<strike>MicroFocus just announced [StormRunner Functional (SRF)](https://software.microfocus.com/en-us/software/functional-testing-as-a-service) which allows testing in the cloud ([promotional video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TGZhDmHFOgg)). You can upload UFT tests (currently only web or mobile) and then schedule the test to run daily, you pay for usage of SRF which covers the AWS instance as well as the UFT license.</strike>

SRF has been discontinued, it is no more, it has ceased to be. StormRunner Functional has expired and gone to meet its maker. It's a stiff, bereft of life. It's pushing up the daisies. SRF is an ex product.

Comment: Thank you for the news update!! This sounds promising, I will definitely have to check it out

Answer (score 1):

you can install the **awscli** and with the help of it, bring up/down your instance on-demand. (from any local client)

an other solution might be the use of the **Jenkins - Amazon EC2 plugin.**

The bigger issue of yours seems to be however making sure that you have an active Desktop, after the machine is started. 
The most viable solution would be setting up *Auto login* on the respective clients. (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=83998)

***Getting the results*** back afterwards has also multiple solution possibilities (store it in S3 and then downloading it with **awscli** is the one I would propose)